# Iterating through a list of arrays and getting a particular value

Tags: java, json, parsing

I had a json file like this:

```
{
   "tags":[
      {
         "key":"category",
         "value":"Generic Secret"
      },
      {
         "key":"category",
         "value":"Secret"
      },
      {
         "key":"cvss_31_severity_rating",
         "value":"none"
      },
      {
         "key":"cvss_score",
         "value":"0"
      },
      {
         "key":"language",
         "value":"javascript"
      },
      {
         "key":"owasp_category",
         "value":"a3-sensitive-data-exposure"
      },
      {
         "key":"sink_method",
         "value":"src/auth/auth.controller.ts::program:validateWithX5UJwt"
      },
      {
         "key":"source_method",
         "value":"src/auth/auth.controller.ts::program:validateWithX5UJwt"
      }
   ]
}
```

I iterated through the tags array:

```
List <String[]> list = response.getBody().jsonPath().getList("response.findings.tags");
for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(k));
}
```

And got something like this:

```
[{key=category, value=Generic Secret}, {key=category, value=Secret}, {key=cvss_31_severity_rating, value=none}, {key=cvss_score, value=0}, {key=language, value=javascript}, {key=owasp_category, value=a3-sensitive-data-exposure}, {key=sink_method, value=src/auth/auth.controller.ts::program:validateWithJKUJwt}, {key=source_method, value=src/auth/auth.controller.ts::program:validateWithJKUJwt}]
```

Now I want to pick the value of `cvss_score`, which in this case is `0`. How can I do this?

Comment: When the key is cvss, you get the value for key. Please, add the code instead of a picture of it, and put some code example.

Comment: `{key=category, value=Generic Secret}` doesn't look like a `String[]`.

Comment: added the json code

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo

Comment: What library are you using to deserialize the JSON data?

Comment: I dont mind adding new libraries, if anyone provides the info

Answer (score -1):

Really naive solution is using the GSON to deserialize the input:

```
private static class Data {

    private List<Entry> tags;

}

private static class Entry {

    private String key;
    private String value;

}

Data data = new Gson().fromJson(input, Data.class);
String result = data.tags.stream()
        .filter(entry -> "cvss_score".equals(entry.key))
        .findFirst()
        .map(entry -> entry.value)
        .orElse(null);
```

Or you can write your own JsonDeserializer to serialize to a Map directly [GSON JsonDeserializer JavaDoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)